# Creating a loop in SQL with reference to previous iteration

Tags: sql, loops, t-sql

I have a dataset with columns:

[image]

What I need to do is to create a loop with such conditions:

1. For Index = 1

- if Column1 >= 1 then **Column2** = 1 and **Column3** = Column1 - 1
- if Column1 < 1 then **Column 2** = 0 and **Column3** = 0

2. For Index > 1

- if Column1 + Column3 (from previous iteration!) >=1 then **Column2** = 1 and **Column3** = Column1 + Column3 (from previos iteration!) - 1
- if Column1 + Column3 (from previous iteration) < 1 then **Column2** = 0 and **Column3** = 0

I need to update this column one row at the time, starting with Index = 1. I have tried to start with such WHILE loop:

```
WHILE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #TABLE WHERE Column2 IS NULL) > 0
UPDATE TOP (1) #TABLE
SET ...
```

And I simply can't achieve my desired outcome like this:

[image]

And of course I really, really want to avoid using Cursor. Thank you for your help!

Comment: I assume, Index column is Primary Key? Then Index = 1 will be only once right?

Comment: Exactly. With each row index increase by 1 and is unique.

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: You are completely right, sorry. I have added "T-SQL" tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a recursive CTE for this, something like:

```
with t as
(
  select * 
  from (values (1,4,null,null),
               (2,0,null,null),
               (3,0,null,null),
               (4,0,null,null),
               (5,2,null,null),
               (6,0,null,null)) v(Id,Column1,Column2,Column3)
), q as
(
  select Id,
         Column1,
         case when Column1 >=1 then 1 else 0 end Column2,
         case when Column1 >=1 then Column1-1 else 0 end Column3
  from t 
  where id = 1
  union all
  select t.id, 
         t.Column1, 
         case when t.Column1 + q.Column3 >= 1 then 1 else 0 end Column2,
         case when t.Column1 + q.Column3 >= 1 then t.Column1+q.Column3-1 else 0 end Column3
         
  from t
  join q
    on q.id = t.id-1
)
select *
from q
```

outputs

```
Id          Column1     Column2     Column3
----------- ----------- ----------- -----------
1           4           1           3
2           0           1           2
3           0           1           1
4           0           1           0
5           2           1           1
6           0           1           0

(6 rows affected)
```